# ThreeJS - Export scene from Blender, Colors Flat

Tags: three.js

I have a 3d room in obj format exported from ArchiCAD.

Imported it to Blender. In Blender room looks like as is.
http://imageshack.us/a/img820/7409/oof5.png

But exported room in json from Blender looks very ugly.
http://imageshack.us/a/img7/517/l12s.png

```
// Room
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( 'textures/room2/room.js', function (geometry, materials)
{
    var  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
    mesh.scale.set(2, 2, 2);
    mesh.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    scene.add(mesh);
});
// Lighting
var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF);
scene.add(light);
```

What I am doing wrong? Article (graphic-sim.com/B_basic_export.html) didn't help me.

Comment: Try reducing the level of the ambient light and add a `THREE.PointLight` to the scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The materials are only reflecting ambient light because that is the only light you have in your scene.

Reduce the level of the ambient light and add a `THREE.PointLight`, for example, to the scene.

three.js r.62